# How to prevent kdeconnectd from starting automatically?

Tags: debian, kde, d-bus, autostart, kde-connect

These don't work: `sudo update-rc.d kdeconnectd disable` `sudo systemctl disable kdeconnectd.service`

There is no script for it in `/etc/init.d/` and the `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.kdeconnect.service` file only has `Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kdeconnectd` set

`sysv-rc-conf`, `rcconf` and `bum` don't list kdeconnect.

`/etc/xdg/autostart/kdeconnectd.desktop` looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kdeconnectd
X-KDE-StartupNotify=false
X-KDE-autostart-phase=0
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
OnlyShowIn=KDE;GNOME;Unity;XFCE;
NoDisplay=true
```

[(Kdeconnectd has port 1716 open all the time when running.)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384306/why-does-kdeconnect-listen-on-port-1716-tcp-all-the-time-how-to-close-the-port) It's not just starting automatically when booting but also a while after ending the process without me opening it.

I'm running Debian 9/KDE.

**Update**: it may be related to a problem with the Dolphin file-explorer: when running dolphin and just navigating around or waiting after a while I'm getting this output which I reported [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=431434):

```
org.kde.kcoreaddons: Error loading plugin "akregatorplugin" "The shared library was not found." 
Plugin search paths are ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins", "/usr/bin") 
The environment variable QT_PLUGIN_PATH might be not correctly set
error activating kdeconnectd: QDBusError("", "")
Cannot initialize model with data QJsonObject() . missing: QJsonValue(string, "urls")
```

Comment: I described it for all of us [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384306/why-does-kdeconnect-listen-on-port-1716-tcp-all-the-time-how-to-close-the-port/509476#509476)

Comment: Setting `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false` worked for me. I also have `X-KDE-autostart-phase=1` instead of 0. Beside that the settings are identical (excluding the Name list at the end of file). I am running GNOME though, so at least there it seems to work as intended KDE Autostart Phases: https://github.com/KDE/kdelibs/blob/1c5b25966136b6099665477616fb4d38a98fd7ef/kinit/README.autostart#L41

From that perhaps phase > 2 could help. From what it say it looks `Hidden = true` should disable. Can not see you have that in the desktop file.

Comment: Modifying `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true` parameter won't help in KDE. You can rename `/etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.kdeconnect.daemon.desktop` launcher instead. Check my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/829628#1389759).

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't need to use KDE Connect even occasionally: you can just uninstall it. At least on my Kubuntu 22.04 setup, `kdeconnect` is an optional package

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, I have solved it by deleting two files: "/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.kdeconnect.service"  and  "/etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.kdeconnect.daemon.desktop". I don't know if it's the proper way to fix it, but it worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same issue and after being at a loss for several minutes as to where was the setting to disable kde connect from autostarting I finally found it.

I had noticed that after unlocking the graphical component and going to the application bar and clicking the button to add a graphical component kde connect had a 1 indicating one such component was enabled. Though I had no idea how to disable it as clicking on its icon brung up the option to remove the miniature box instead.

So here's how I did it: right click the miniature box and open its settings.
In the miniature box settings window scroll down to the additional component section until you reach kde connect in the list. Untick the checkbox to disable it, and apply the new settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where do I find the "miniature box" to click for opening the settings?

Comment: I guess you mean the "system tray". It disables the component, but it is in fact still running.